# Why is AndroidTest directory created every time I create a new project in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I noticed that a directory AndroidTest is created, with a java file "ApplicationTest", every time I create a new project. What is its use? Any impact if I delete it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio : difference between src/androidTest and src/main folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30980890/android-studio-difference-between-src-androidtest-and-src-main-folders)