# Android Studio : difference between src/androidTest and src/main folders?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio.

My questions are :

- what is the difference between src/androidTest and src/main folders ?
- where should put all my classes ?

Answer (score 5):

Refer [Android Studio Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html)

Each instance of Android Studio contains a project with one or more application modules. Each application module folder contains the complete source sets for that module, including `src/main/` and `src/androidTest/`directories. For the most part, you will need to modify the files under each module's `src/main/` directory for source code updates, the gradle.build file for build specification and the files under `src/androidTest/` directory for test case creation.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio 1.0 the scheme has changed a little bit.

Your path should be (app)/src/androidTest/java/com/myapp/HelloWorldTest.java

Here's how I set up Unit Tests in a new Android Studio project:

Open app in Android Studio.
Set the Project explorer (left hand window) to display 'Project' mode.
 Tap the little drop-down at the top left and select 'Project'.
Right click the 'src' directory, 'New -> Directory'.
Call new directory androidTest
Right click androidTest and add a 'java' directory. 
It will appear in green (indicating it's a test src directory).
Now right-click again and add a package, e.g. com.mycompany.myapp.tests
Add a new class that extends AndroidTestCase.

http://envyandroid.com/content/images/2014/02/project-structure.png

For putting the classes:-
src folder --> main folder --> then java

Comment: I think this question is about the application classes, and not tests, although the OP is not directly states that.

Comment: I checked it, but it is actually unrelated to your answer, and confusing.

Comment: Also, unit tests should be under the *src/test/java* folder, not *src/androidTest/java* (the latter is for instrumentation tests).

Answer (score 0):

To be precise on androidTest:

Unit tests run on a local JVM on your development machine. Gradle plugin will compile source code found in src/test/ and execute it using the usual Gradle testing mechanisms.

To answer in a word. The main difference between androidTest and android and main folders is the former is for "**Testing**" while the later is for Development.

Comment: You are explaining unit tests, but you connect it to the `androidTest` folder which is for instrumentation tests, not unit tests. Also there is no `android` folder which you are referencing in your last sentence.